# Directive to externalize view not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

I'm using [pageslide directive](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide) in order to display a lateral sliding menu when I click on an icon.

This is the usual way to do it, and its working :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <span ng-controller="slideController as s">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="s.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
          <div pageslide ps-open="s.isActive" ps-side="left">
            <div style="padding:20px">
              <h2>Hello Pageslide</h2>
              <p>Put here whatever I want in the lateral menu</p>
              <a ng-click="s.toggle()" class="button" >Close</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </span>
  <a class="navbar-brand text-danger" href="javascript:void(0)">Balrog</a>
</div>
```

But I would lilke to make the menu content in an external template, so I'm trying this :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <span ng-controller="slideController as s">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="s.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
    <menu-item isActive="s.isActive"></menu-item>
  </span>
  <a class="navbar-brand text-danger" href="javascript:void(0)">Balrog</a>
</div>
```

with this as menu.html :

```
<div pageslide ps-open="s.isActive" ps-side="left">
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2>Hello Pageslide</h2>
    <p>Put here whatever I want in the lateral menu</p>
    <a ng-click="s.toggle()" class="button" >Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

also, here is the related controller :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('BalrogApp').controller('slideController', function(){

  this.isActive= false; // This will be binded using the ps-open attribute

  this.toggle = function(){
    this.isActive= !this.isActive
  }

});
```

and the `<menu-item>` directive :

```
angular.module('BalrogApp').directive('menuItem', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "views/menu.html",
    scope: {
      isActive: '='
    },
    controller: 'slideController',
    controllerAs: 's',
    bindToController: true
  }
});
```

So it's not working this way, maybe it is because the main view (including the `<menu-item`>) is itself included in the main page thanks to `<ng-view>` ?

Or maybe the `pageslide-directive` requires the `<div pageslide ...>` and its parent element to be on the same file ?

I can tell from the console that `toggle()` is called and changes `isActive` in both cases but it's not opening the menu with the directive version.

And also, adding `ng-controller="slideController as s"` to the root `<div>` with the `pageslide` attribute didn't change anything.

So how can I make this work with the menu in another file ?

Comment: personally I HATE ng-include... I prefer creating a directive... change ng-include to a directive since you're trying to manipulate the DOM .... if you want more assistance please add a plunker

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: @JesúsQuintana : I'm using AngularJS v1.4.7

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to replace `<div ng-include="menu.html"></div>` with `<div ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>`. According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude, you have to wrap string constants in single quotes.

Comment: correct, still ng-include SUCKS... custom directives are much more coherent and are the better choice

Comment: Nope, adding quotes did not fix it. I'm gonna try with a directive like suggested though.

Comment: I updated the initial post with the directive a^^rpacj and posted more informations. Still not working though, any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you not use ng-include. You can get the same approach using directive instead.

For example:

Menu html

```
<div pageslide ps-open="vm.checked" ps-side="left">
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2>Hello Pageslide</h2>
    <p>Put here whatever I want in the lateral menu</p>
    <a ng-click="vm.toggle()" class="button" >Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
function Controller() {
}

Controller.prototype.toggle = function() {
  this.checked = !this.checked;
}

angular
  .module('BalrogApp')
  .directive('menuItem', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'urltomenu.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        checked: '='
      },
      controller: Controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    }
  })
```

Main template

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <span ng-controller="slideController as s">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)"
       ng-click="s.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>
    <menu-item checked="s.checked"><menu-item>
  </span>
  <a class="navbar-brand text-danger" href="javascript:void(0)">Balrog</a>
</div>
```

This approach give you more power. All the logic is inside the directive controller and you could reuse this element each time. The scope attribute *checked* is the *"bridge"* between your main template if change outside also change inside and also the other way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it this way but it's not working neither, I updated the initial post with this approach and posted more informations. ANy idea what's wrong ?